# How resource-intensive are 10 back-to-back SQL queries using one HiveContext?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code snippet that will run 10 sqls using the same `HiveContext` in Spark 1.5.1.

```
//initialize sparkcontext and hivecontext
//10 SQL that manipulate large data to run one by one
val sqls = Array("insert overwrite x select a join b on c","foo", "bar"....)
for(i <- 0 to 10) {
 hiveContext.sql(sqls(i)).collect
}
```

My question is, when the nth sql is finished, what's the affect on the next sql from the resource perspective. That is, when will the resources that the nth sql used be released. For example, the memory that the nth sql uses(eg, the memory used for hashjoin).

Answer (score 1):

Memory (de)allocation may depend on the version of Spark in use, but any query in Spark is "transformed" into one or more Spark jobs. See SQL tab in web UI to learn more.

Since you are not caching the Datasets you may safely assume that there is no memory allocation in a long run. When memory is required, the other Datasets are evicted from memory and lost. Use Storage and Executors tabs to explore it in more details.